# Is there a command to list the locks aquired by libvirt/virtlockd?

Tags: libvirt

I have a setup using virtlockd's *indirect locks* (that use empty files with long hex strings as file names) on a shared filesystem being used by multiple cluster nodes.
I can see that each node has some file locks on some of those "hex files", but I cannot tell from the "hex file name" what the object actually locked is.

So I wonder:
Is there a command that displays what objects are locked by the current node?
I mean something specific to libvirt or virtlockd, but not something like `lslocks`.

The background is that sometimes when live-migrating a VM, libvirtd claims some of those magic "long hex file names" wouldn't be locked.
It might be a bug in libvirtd, but anyway.

Comment: Some info is here: Introduction to libvirt locking mechanism virtlockd
 https://programmersought.com/article/11863543196/

Comment: I filed an enhancement request: https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/130